Why does my three.js code does not execute on MacOS? Error: "Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call". It works fine on Windows
`To represent a 3D model with particles, points are used, and the shape changes through scrolling.
However, the code works correctly on Windows but fails to execute on Mac.
An error occurs with the message: "GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call."
Even when reducing the number of particles to 100 for testing, the same error occurs.
I need help understanding whether it's an issue with the 3D model or if there is code that doesn't work on Mac.
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {useFrame, useLoader} from '@react-three/fiber';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import {DRACOLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader';
import {MeshSurfaceSampler} from 'three/examples/jsm/math/MeshSurfaceSampler';
import {mergeGeometries} from 'three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import gsap from 'gsap';

export default function ParticleModel({url, position, scroll}) {
  const ref = useRef();
  const morphRatioRef = useRef({value: 0});
  const {scene} = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url, (loader) => {
    const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
    dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/');
    loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const amount = 100000;
    const geometries = [];
    const positionsStart = new Float32Array(amount * 3);
    const positionsEnd = new Float32Array(amount * 3);

    scene.traverse((child) => {
      if (child.isMesh) {
        const geom = child.geometry.clone().toNonIndexed();
        geom.applyMatrix4(child.matrixWorld);
        geometries.push(geom);
      }
    });

    const mergedGeometry = mergeGeometries(geometries);
    const sampler = new MeshSurfaceSampler(new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry)).build();
    // const particles = new Float32Array(amount * 3);
    const tempPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      sampler.sample(tempPosition);
      positionsEnd.set([tempPosition.x, tempPosition.y, tempPosition.z], i * 3);
    }

    // Create grid-like initial positions
    const gridSize = Math.sqrt(amount);
    const spacing = 20;
    let index = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
        if (index >= amount) break;
        const x = (i - gridSize / 2) * (spacing);
        const z = (j - gridSize / 2) * (spacing);
        const y = Math.sin(x * 0.01) * 10 + Math.sin(z * 0.01) * 10 + 100; // Wave effect with Y offset
        positionsStart.set([x, y, z], index * 3);
        index++;
      }
      if (index > amount) break;
    }

    mergedGeometry.setAttribute('positionStart', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positionsStart, 3));
    mergedGeometry.setAttribute('positionEnd', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positionsEnd, 3));
    ref.current.geometry = mergedGeometry;

    const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        morphRatio: morphRatioRef.current,
        time: { value: 0 },
      },
      vertexShader: `
        uniform float morphRatio;
        uniform float time;
        attribute vec3 positionStart;
        attribute vec3 positionEnd;
        
        void main() {
          vec3 transformed = mix(positionStart, positionEnd, morphRatio);
           // float wave = sin(time * 2.0 + transformed.x * 0.1) * 2.0 + sin(time * 2.0 + transformed.z * 0.1) * 2.0;
          // transformed.y += wave; // Add wave effect to y position
          gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(transformed, 1.0);
          gl_PointSize = mix(12.0, 2.0, morphRatio); // 파티클 사이즈
        }
      `,
      fragmentShader: `
        void main() {
          vec2 coord = gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5);
          float distance = length(coord);
          float alpha = 0.5 - smoothstep(0.4, 0.5, distance);
          if (distance > 0.5) discard; // Ensure circular shape
          gl_FragColor = vec4(0.1, 0.4, 0.7, alpha); // Adjust color if needed
        }
      `,
      transparent: true,
    });
    ref.current.material = material;

    // Set up scroll event listener
    const handleScroll = (e) => {
      console.log(e)
      // const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      // const maxScroll = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
      // morphRatioRef.current.value = scrollTop / maxScroll;
      // console.log(scrollTop/maxScroll)
    };



    // window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      // window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };

  }, [scene]);
  useEffect(() => {
    morphRatioRef.current.value = scroll
  }, [scroll]);

  useFrame(({clock, camera}) => {
    if (ref.current) {
      // Keep the wave animation running
      // Keep the wave animation running
      const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
      morphRatioRef.current.value = Math.min(morphRatioRef.current.value, 1); // Ensure morphRatio stays between 0 and 1
      ref.current.material.uniforms.morphRatio.value = morphRatioRef.current.value;
      // ref.current.material.uniforms.time.value = elapsedTime;

      // Update particle model position based on morphRatio
      ref.current.position.y = morphRatioRef.current.value * 100 - 220; // Adjust the multiplier and offset to control the Y movement
      ref.current.position.x = morphRatioRef.current.value * 100 - 20; // Adjust the multiplier and offset to control the Y movement


      // Update camera position based on morphRatio
      camera.position.z = morphRatioRef.current.value * 100 + 100 ; // Adjust the multiplier to control t
      camera.position.y = morphRatioRef.current.value * 100 - 60; // Adjust the multiplier to control t
    }
  });

  return <points ref={ref} position={position}/>;
}

Below is the Component where Canvas and gsap are declared.
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'
import {Canvas} from '@react-three/fiber'
import ParticleModel from "./ParticleModel.jsx";
import CenterTextMain from "./CenterTextMain.jsx";
import SemLoopLogo from "./SemLoopLogo.jsx";

import './ThreeMain.css'
import MainProductCard from "./MainProductCard.jsx";
import gsap from "gsap";

export default function ThreeMain() {
  const threeRef = useRef(null);
  const [sectionScroll, setSectionScroll] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
      const viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
      gsap.to(threeRef.current, {
        scrollTrigger : {
          trigger: threeRef.current,
          start: `${viewHeight} center`,
          end: `${viewHeight*3} center`,
          scrub: 1,
          // markers: true,
          onUpdate: (self) => {
            setSectionScroll(self.progress)
            // const progress = self.progress;

          }
        }
      })



  }, []);

  return (
    <section className={'three-main'} ref={threeRef}>
      <CenterTextMain/>
      <Canvas

        camera={{fov: 25, far: 1000, position: [80, 30, 320]}}
        style={{background: '#ffffff', position: 'sticky', top: '0', left: '0', width: '100%', height: '100vh',}}
      >
        <ambientLight color='white' intensity={1} position={[0, 1000, 200]}/>
        <spotLight position={[0, 1000, 1000]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} decay={0} intensity={Math.PI}/>
        <pointLight position={[-10, 1000, 1000]} decay={0} intensity={Math.PI}/>
        <ParticleModel url='/three_model/bone_white.gltf' position={[0, -170, 0]} scroll={sectionScroll}/>
        {/*<OrbitControls />*/}
      </Canvas>
      <SemLoopLogo/>
      <MainProductCard />
    </section>

  )
}


Maybe this will interested you https://discourse.threejs.org/t/vertex-buffer-is-not-big-enough-for-the-draw-call-only-on-mac-computers/43628/8
